# Passing on multiple GET variables with the "next" parameter in the URL

Tags: php, redirect, parameters, get

I'm having issues passing on multiple `$_GET` variables with "next".

I'm redirecting users to the login page:

```
login?next=initial_page?email=john_doe@gmail.com&activate_key=1421sdxzcxz213xz
```

The problem is that the activation key is treated as a second `$_GET` parameter on the login page (along with "next"), instead of being part of the redirected $_GET.

A solution would be to use cookies, is there any way I can still make this work with `$_GET` though?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode the parameter data--something like this:

```
echo '<a href="login?next=' . urlencode('initial_page?email=john_doe@gmail.com&activate_key=1421sdxzcxz213xz') . '">link</a>';
```

This will produce a link like this:

```
<a href="login?next=initial_page%3Femail%3Djohn_doe%40gmail.com%26activate_key%3D1421sdxzcxz213xz">link</a>
```

...which will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can URL-encode the `&` as `%26`.

Answer (score 0):

```
login?next=initial_page?email=john_doe@gmail.com&amp;activate_key&amp;1421sdxzcxz213xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('Location: login?next='.rawurlencode('initial_page?email=john_doe@gmail.com&activate_key=1421sdxzcxz213xz'));
```

which automatically generates a 302 response.

Test code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['next']))
    print $_GET['next'];
else
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?next='.rawurlencode('initial_page?email=john_doe@gmail.com&activate_key=1421sdxzcxz213xz'));
?>
```